# JQuery drag & drop with tabs does not clone node

Tags: jquery, tabs, clone, draggable

I tried to get the following code working where an element from a selectable should be cloned and appended to a sortable in a different tab. However, the node from the selectable is not cloned at all but instead removed and appended to the sortable. Here's the code:

```html
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2 /jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.15.custom.css">
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
    var $tabs = $('#tabs').tabs();
    $( "#selectable" ).selectable();
    $('li', '#selectable').draggable({
        connectToSortable: '#sortable',
        helper: 'clone',
        revert: 'invalid'
    });

var $tab_items = $('ul:first li', $tabs).droppable({
    accept : '#selectable li',
    hoverClass : 'ui-state-hover',
    drop : function(event, ui) {
        var $item = $(this);
        var $list = $($item.find('a').attr('href')).find('.connectedSortable');
        $tabs.tabs('select', $tab_items.index($item));
        $(this).appendTo($list).show('slow');
    }
});

$('#selectable, #sortable').disableSelection();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#tab-selectable">Tab1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-sortable">Tab2</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tab-selectable">
    <ul id="selectable">
        <li id="e101" class="ui-state-default">Num 1</li>
            <li id="e102" class="ui-state-default">Num 2</li>
        <li id="e103" class="ui-state-default">Num 3</li>
        <li id="e104" class="ui-state-default">Num 4</li>
        <li id="e105" class="ui-state-default">Num 5</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="tab-sortable">
    <ul id="sortable" class="connectedSortable ui-helper-reset">
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: With a simple ui.draggable.clone() it finally worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a simple `ui.draggable.clone()` it finally worked.